# Read Bluetooth Message in External android app

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I'am a newbie to android Bluetooth and I want to read and store the Bluetooth message in external android app(mine) using internal storage or sqlite. I have tried the android bluetooth-chat sample from GitHub but I don't know how to implement my idea.

Any help would be helpful and thanks

Comment: What you want to implement. Clearify your question

Comment: Need to store any messages from Bluetooth in external app(mine)

Comment: The first step in solving a problem is learning to specifically and precisely state what it is you are trying to do.  Chances are, when you do that, you will see that your question has already been asked and answered several times, both here an elsewhere on the web.  If you are not sure yet of what the options are, spend some time looking at possibly related functionality in existing apps - and not necessarily only those having anything to do with bluetooth, as that seems to be only a minor aspect of your question.

Comment: Inside handleMessage there is once case Read_Message, in that case, you can store the messages.

Answer (score 2):

Exchange of bluetooth messages is covered in the `android.bluetooth` section of the api.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#ManagingAConnection

Here is a basic example of managing a connection and sending/receiving messages:

```
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
private final InputStream mmInStream;
private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
    mmSocket = socket;
    InputStream tmpIn = null;
    OutputStream tmpOut = null;

    // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
    // member streams are final
    try {
        tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
        tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) { }

    mmInStream = tmpIn;
    mmOutStream = tmpOut;
}

public void run() {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  // buffer store for the stream
    int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

    // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
    while (true) {
        try {
            // Read from the InputStream
            bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
            // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity
            mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                    .sendToTarget();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            break;
        }
    }
}

/* Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device */
public void write(byte[] bytes) {
    try {
        mmOutStream.write(bytes);
    } catch (IOException e) { }
}

/* Call this from the main activity to shutdown the connection */
public void cancel() {
    try {
        mmSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) { }
}
```

}